# Arduino Unoのデータ型?

Tags: arduino

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
    int a=10;
    long b = a * 10000; //①
//  long b = 100000;  //②
    Serial.print(b);
    Serial.print("\n");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Arduino Unoに、上記コードを転送し、シリアルモニタを確認すると
①では、-31072が表示され
②では、100000が表示されます。
これは、何故でしょうか？

Comment: Arduino を持っていないので確認できないのですが、`long b = (long)a * 10000L` だとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: この場合は、明示的キャストでＯＫでした。ただ実際には時分秒を連結した long b = (long)(HH*10000+MM*100+SS)が欲しかったのですが、こちらの場合はやはり()内でintのマイナスになってしまいました。

Comment: taku_s さん、その場合は `long b = (long)HH * 10000L + (long)MM * 100L + (long)SS` で良かろうと思います。また、文字列として連結する方法の方が目的にあっているかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arduino Unoでは、`int`は符号付16bit整数として扱うようなので、「`a * 10000`」の演算結果がオーバーフローしているからと思います。(100000の下位16bitを符号付整数としてみると、ちょうど「-31702」になります)

＃参考: [Auduino日本語リファレンス:int(整数型)](http://www.musashinodenpa.com/arduino/ref/index.php?f=0&pos=1105)

`long`は符号付32bitのようなので、次のような挙動の差になっているのではないでしょうか?

- ①は、オーバーフローした結果がaに代入される
- ②は、コンパイラが`100000`をlong定数として扱ってaに代入される